# IEnumerable does not allow access to sub items

Tags: c#, ienumerable

To make a long story short.
I have the following code:

```
class MyList : IEnumerable
{
    private List<string> T1 = new List<string>();
    private List<string> T2 = new List<string>();
    private List<string> T3 = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Name { set { T1 = value; } get { return T1; } }
    public List<string> DataType { set { T2 = value; } get { return T2; } }
    public List<string> Nullable { set { T3 = value; } get { return T3; } }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }
    public MyList<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyList<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>>(T1, T2, T2);
    }
}
```

What I want is to access it like this:

```
       MyList ml = new MyList();
       foreach (var item in ml)
       {
           str = item.Name;
       }
```

It does not let me access the subitem, like item.Name, or item.DataType.

Comment: Provided code gives a lot of compile errors. Is that the problem? Or do you have another problem?

Comment: Likely you want to implement `IEnumerable<T>` instead. But I think you have larger issues. Maybe you need a single class object to represent a single `Name`, `Datatype`, `Nullable` set.

Comment: @Styxxy the code doesn't give any compiling problems, all I want is to be able to access it like the small chunk of code below the question.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair would you mind shedding some light on the IEnumerable<T> please?

Comment: @Johnny: Sorry, I couldn't answer your question earlier. [HOKBONG's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816041/1269654) mostly sums up what I was I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to expose the functionality you describe (3 lists collectively representing a set of items) you can do it, but you still need to expose a new type for the benefit of your enumerator.

```
class MyItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public bool Nullable { get; set; }
}

class MyList : IEnumerable<MyItem>
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    public List<string> DataTypes { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Nullables { get; set; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // assuming all lists are the same length
        for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
            yield return new MyItem {
                Name = Names[i],
                DataType = DataTypes[i],
                Nullable = Nullables[i]
            };
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
MyList ml = new MyList();
ml.Names = new [] { "AccountNum", "Value", "Owner" } .ToList();
ml.DataTypes = new [] { "nvarchar(50)", "decimal(14,6)", "nvarchar(50)" } .ToList();
ml.Nullables = new [] { false, false, true } .ToList();

foreach (var item in ml)
{
    str = item.Name;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped, btw that actually is a bool :) just forgot to change it. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are trying to make a list of things, each of which has 3 properties: Name, DataType, Nullable.  Try this:

```
class MyItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Nullable { get; set; }  // also, consider making this bool
}
```

Then make a list of those.

Comment: @CJS what im trying to do is have 3 List<string> in the class, it's like a customized Tuple if u will.

Comment: You're implementing a list of customized tuples (your ideal sample usage demonstrates this).  Rather than use 3 parallel lists to achieve the objective (where T1[0], T2[0], and T3[0] collectively describe one object), you should collect the three properties in their own type.  Making a list of them is then trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from [@CSJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21817331/584676), I would suggest:

```
public class MyItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Nullable { get; set; }  // also, consider making this bool
}

public class MyItemList : IEnumerable<MyItem>
{
    private List<MyItem> MyItems = new List<MyItem>();

    public IEnumerator<MyItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.MyItems.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely that the OP will really need to implement a custom `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just using a `List<MyItem>`.

Comment: @HighCore: +1 True, just in case OP needs more logic encapsulated in the MyItemList class..

Comment: @HOKBONG is it possible for MyItem not to have it's own class?

Comment: If your purpose is to enumerate the 3 lists of List<string> you will need the MyItemList class. What exactly do you try to accomplish here?

Comment: @HOKBONG what im trying to accomplish have 3 variables name, datatype...etc, each containing a list, with that said, I want to be able to use foreach to get all 3 lists, look at the foreach statement I provided in my question. thanks for replying